# Remount filesystem readonly

Tags: linux, mount

I want to remount /dev/sda2 [mounted on /var/www] as readonly

```
# mount -o remount,ro /var/www
mount: /var/www is busy
```

There are no open files on that filesystem

```
# fuser -v -m /var/www
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/var/www:            root     kernel mount /var/www
# lsof -V /var/www
lsof: no file system use located: /var/www
```

Nothing nfs-like is running. No swapfiles under `/var/www`. No loop devices in use.

Why is `/var/www` still busy?

Nothing mounted under `/var/www`:

```
# mount
/dev/root on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodelalloc)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=155344k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=310684k)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=310684k)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/sda2 on /var/www type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodelalloc)
```

Comment: Anything mounted below /var/www?

Comment: Nothing mounted below `/var/www`. I added the mounts in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By killing various processes I found out that gamin was keeping the mount busy. I still wonder why this didn't show up in either `lsof` nor `fuser`